# Why i don't get data after ajax posts requests?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Why i don't get data after `AJAX` posts requests ?

When i use

```
$('#fid1 input,select').attr('disabled','disbaled');
```

for disabling form input between ajax send post process

and use

```
$('#fid1 input,select').removeAttr('disabled');
```

for enabling form input after ajax send post success

**index.php**

```
<form method="post" id="fid1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check_box_one" name="color_check" value="one" onclick="sedn_ajax()">1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check_box_two" name="color_check" value="two" onclick="sedn_ajax()">2<br>
</form>

<script>
function sedn_ajax(){
    $('#fid1 input,select').attr('disabled','disbaled');
    $('#demoajax').hide();
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#fid1').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
            $('#demoajax').show();
            $('#demoajax').html(data);
            $('#fid1 input,select').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    return false;
}
$(document).ready(sedn_ajax());
</script>
```

**test.php**

```
<?PHP echo $_POST['color_check']; ?>
```

Comment: Disabled elements are not included in a form request or in the data generated from `.serialize()`.

Comment: how can i disable form and send data to test.php

Comment: Serialize the form and then disable the inputs, if that's your goal.

Comment: Please use the array index as strings: `$_POST['color_check'];`

Comment: @TiesonT. post the answer...:)

Comment: how can i do `Serialize the form and then disable the inputs` could you please give me some code?

Comment: Funny that _disbaled_ is truthy - just move the serialise to before the disabled of course:  `var sFrm = $('#fid1").serialize(); $('#fid1 input,select').attr('disabled','disabled');`

Comment: EG:         `data: $('#fid1').serialize(),
                                                                      $('#fid1 input,select').attr('disabled','disbaled');`

Comment: Or set the var outside the Ajax call

Comment: @mplungjan `disabled` is true simply by being present, so the `="whatever"` bit is (technically) irrelevant; `disabled="disabled"` is something only older versions of IE require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues

```
function sedn_ajax(){
    $('#fid1 input,select').attr('disabled','disbaled');  //spelled disbaled wrong - lucky it is truthy. You also are slecting all selects in the page, not just the elements in the form. 
    $('#demoajax').hide();
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#fid1').serialize(),  //serialize does not read disabled inputs
        success: function(data){
            $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
            $('#demoajax').show();
            $('#demoajax').html(data);
            $('#fid1 input,select').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    return false;
}
$(document).ready(sedn_ajax());  //WRONG should not be ()
```

with the changes

```
function sedn_ajax(){
    var data = $('#fid1').serialize(); //read the form values before disabled
    $("#fid1").find('input,select').prop('disabled', true);  //set it to true and use prop, not attr
    $('#demoajax').hide();
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,  //use the variable
        success: function(data){
            $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
            $('#demoajax').show();
            $('#demoajax').html(data);
            $("#fid1").find('input,select').prop('disabled', false);   //set it to false and use prop()
            }
        });
    return false;
}
$(document).ready(sedn_ajax);  //No ()
```

And how can it be improved, store look-ups into variables and do not keep looking up the elements in the DOM.